# Htaccess inside a folder

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

We are trying to make a change of domain for a wordpress.

The blog is in a subfolder called "blog".

The old domain is

http://www.peluches-et-jouets-en-bois.fr/blog

We want all the pages of the blog to be redirected to :

http://www.peluchesetjouetsenbois.fr/blog

It does work for the home page of the blog, but as soon as we go to another page of the blog, then it doesn't work anymore.

Here is what we have so far.

WordPress

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /blog/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?peluches-et-jouets-en-bois.fr$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.peluchesetjouetsenbois.fr/blog/$1  [L,R=301]
    </IfModule>

    # END Wo
```

If someone can help us on that, that would be great :)

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place redirection rule before existing WP rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?peluches-et-jouets-en-bois\.fr$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.peluchesetjouetsenbois.fr/blog/$1  [L,NE,R=301]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
```